# Excel: make a cell with a sum copyable to an other excel file

Tags: excel

I am doing some work with excell sheets and now i need to do a lot of copy/paste by hand.
What i am looking for is this:

```
A1 = 1  
A2 = 1  
A3 = A1 + A2
```

Now when I copy A3 and want to put it in an other excel file, it does not work.
How do I get the content of A3 in a copy/pasteable cell?

(example is simplified to illustrate the mechanic)

Greets and thanks!

Comment: The content? After you paste hit `CTRL` and select one of the options, Paste Value, Formulas, Formulas with Formatting, Formatting, take your pick.

Comment: Much appreciated!